# Within an XML Schema, is it possible to inherit from a complex type but restrict content to a numeric value?

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm trying to write an XML schema that will validate XML configuration files that a program can translate into a set of [pipes and filters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn568100.aspx). All "endpoints" within a data source pipeline should be able to be passive (only generate data in response to a request) or active (they continuously generate data at a specified rate by auto-generating their own requests).

This means that if we assume `Constant`, `SimulatedSource` and `NullSource` to be examples of data source endpoint elements that can be specified within these configuration files, the following XML should be considered valid:

```
<Constant>5</Constant>
<Constant updateRate="100">5</Constant>
<SimulatedSource updateRate="200" />
<NullSource />
```

The trouble I'm having is with defining a schema to validate `Constant` elements - these elements should *only allow numeric content* but *permit an optional `updateRate` attribute*. Within the XML Schema, I've written the following base type:

```
<!-- Generic source type -->
<xs:complexType name="BaseSourceType">
    <xs:attribute name="updateRate" type="xs:double" />
</xs:complexType>
```

I've started on `ConstantSourceType` but I'm not sure how to continue:

```
<xs:complexType name="ConstantSourceType">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="BaseSourceType">
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

One makeshift solution could be the following:

```
<xs:complexType name="ConstantSourceType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:double">
            <xs:attribute name="updateRate" type="xs:double" />
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

However, I'm not in favour of this solution because this would mean I'd need to manually update this type definition whenever I changed what should be treated as its base type (`BaseSourceType`).